# TensorFlow can not add training data through placeholder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Good day to all. Studying TF. Made an example with adding data through placeholder and it does not work. As I understand it, fetch_batch creates batchy just as a string and cannot feed them through feed_dict. But why and how to fix do not understand. I would be very grateful for the help.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape

learning_rate = 0.1
n_epochs = 1000

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_housing_data = scaler.fit_transform(housing.data)

scaled_housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), scaled_housing_data]

#X = tf.constant(scaled_housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
#y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n+1), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="y")

def fetch_batch (batch_index, batch_size, epoch):
    np.random.seed (epoch * batch_size + batch_size) 
    indices = np.random.randint (m, size=batch_size) 
    X_batch = scaled_housing_data_plus_bias [indices]
    y_batch = housing.target.reshape(-1, 1) [indices]
    return X_batch, y_batch

batch_size = 100



theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, seed=42), name="theta")
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="prediction")
erorr = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(erorr), name="mse")
#gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), erorr, name="gradients")
#training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer (learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse)


n_batches = int(np.ceil(m / batch_size))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for batch_index in range(n_batches):
            X_batch, y_batch = fetch_batch (batch_index, batch_size, epoch)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
            if epoch % 100 == 0 :
                print("Epoch:", epoch, "MSE:", mse.eval())
```

but in the end I get an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X_11' with dtype float and shape [?,9]
     [[{{node X_11}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,9], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node mse_12/_7}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_15_mse_12", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-46a547b04ceb> in <module>()
     56             sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
     57             if epoch % 100 == 0 :
---> 58                 print("Epoch:", epoch, "MSE:", mse.eval())
     59 
     60 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    711 
    712     """
--> 713     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    714 
    715 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   5155                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   5156                        "graph.")
-> 5157   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   5158 
   5159 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X_11' with dtype float and shape [?,9]
     [[node X_11 (defined at <ipython-input-19-46a547b04ceb>:23)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,9], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node mse_12/_7}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_15_mse_12", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'X_11', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-46a547b04ceb>", line 23, in <module>
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n+1), name="X")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1747, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 5206, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X_11' with dtype float and shape [?,9]
     [[node X_11 (defined at <ipython-input-19-46a547b04ceb>:23)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,9], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node mse_12/_7}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_15_mse_12", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: This site in _english only_ - use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ for russian

Answer (score 0):

```
print("MSE=%s" % sess.run(mse, feed_dict={X:X_train, y:y_train}))
```

or

```
_, mse_value = sess.run([training_op, mse], feed_dict={X:X_train, y:y_train})
print("MSE=%s" % mse_value)
```